# why java compiler copies the instance initializer block in the constructor after the first statement super()?

Tags: java

The java compiler copies the instance initialization block in the constructor after the first statement super(). We all know that the super() is used to invoke immediate parent class constructor. Even i doesn't inherit any parent class the compiler automatically add the super() in the constructor. So, i want to know that what is the reason for add super() when i use instance initialization block ?

[Image to clear my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vODrk.jpg)

Comment: *"Even i doesn't inherit any parent class"* It extends `Object`.

Comment: but you doesn't understand my point. There is no inheritence of the class so where the super() points ?

Comment: @rajatagarwal that can **never** be the case. If your `class` does not `extends` a parent, the compiler will add `extends Object`.

Comment: okh,  it seems fine

Comment: I already told you, that it inherits from `Object` and you pretend again, it doesn't?

Comment: @BoristheSpider except for `Object` itself ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer @Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have to initialise the parent of a class before you initialise it otherwise you have no idea what state the parent's fields are in. This means that the `super()` has to go before everything else.

> There is no inheritence of the class so where the super() points ?

Only `Object` has no parent. All other classes have a parent which ultimate inherits from `Object`.

Comment: i got it.. I am the beginner in java.  So,  i don't know about the object class. Now i got it.  Thanks for your answer.
I also explain the object class  **The Object class is the parent class of all the classes in java bydefault. In other words, it is the topmost class of java.**

Comment: @rajatagarwal correct. Object is the only class without a parent.

Comment: can you give me some reference where i have to learn the complete java .

Comment: @rajatagarwal I would read the Java Language Specification and try out different syntax to see would it works.